# Preenchendo uma série de imagens a partir de dados em uma tabela

Tags: python, imagem, processamento-de-imagens

Preciso fazer carteirinhas para cerca de 500 pessoas, tenho uma tabela com o nome e imagem anexada e quero saber como colocar esses dados no template das carteirinhas.

Comment: O que já tentaste? o que queres é incluir texto fazer uma imagem 'template' é isso?

Comment: então  -se quiser fazer uma oferta de trabalho freelance para alguém fazer o código para você, a sugestão é usar outros sites. Aqui, é melhor você detalhar o que você já pensou em fazer, e algum código ou psudo-coddigo do que está pensando - de preferencia com pelo menos a parte que acessa os dados que você já existem em um exemplo de código funcional.

Comment: Se conseguir, posta aqui pra vermos.